# Android app is not consistent with all resolutions

Tags: android, user-interface, resolution

I have just finished designing my android app and when I tried changing the resolutions, to check if my app looks the same for all devices, I could not notice that the app's design is twisted in all of the resolutions with the exception of the resolution I design for.

**Long story short**: What can I do so my app will look the same for all resolutions and devices?

Comment: Have you looked at http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html ?

Comment: Yes, of course - But I was woundering if there is a better way... Somehow to make the whole layout change according to the device resolution

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are a couple of issues you could be having but without examples of what's happening it's hard to tell where you are making the mistake.

Number one could be that you are using standard pixels instead of dip or are using absolute layouts or one of the many things mentioned in 
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html as referenced by both hardsky and bos.

Another alternative could be that you are simply thinking about your layouts incorrectly. For instance defining a views padding from the left in order to center it in the screen will totally fail when put on any screen with doesn't end up having dimensions which pan out to 320x480dip. Try to ensure that you are always defining your view placements by their intentions directly rather than a secondary attribute which pans out to be the same on standard resolutions.

Comment: First of all - thank you for the thorough answer.
I have read the article, and I'm using relative layouts, and using "dp" or "centerVerticle" and such...
The Problem is this:
http://img638.imageshack.us/img638/7292/examplefs.png

Comment: well, something things are clearly not properly relative there. No way to tell what without seeing what you are actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

May be different layouts for different resolutions?
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: I already searched the web...
But I was woundering if there is a better way...
Somehow to make the whole layout change according to the device resolution